# Failed qfnra-nlsat prevents other tactics?

Tags: z3

Using Z3 4.4.1 or master, the following input gives `unknown`:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun z () Int)

(assert (and (> x 0) (< x 10)))
(assert (and (> y 0) (< y 10)))
(assert (and (> z 0) (< z 10)))
(assert (= (* z z) (+ (* x x) (* y y))))

(check-sat-using (or-else qfnra-nlsat smt))
```

If I switch the order of the `qfnra-nlsat` and `smt` tactics, then Z3 will return `sat`, which is the correct solution.  The way it works right now, I'm basically forced to use `qfnra-nlsat` at the very end of my strategy. However, this is not optimal for me.

Is the above behaviour a bug?  It seems like `qfnra-nlsat` leaves some unwanted changes to the model, when I would expect the model to be unchanged if `qfnra-nlsat` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead

```
     (check-sat-using (and-then qfnra-nlsat smt))
```

This is subtle:
The qfnra-nlsat tactic fails to establish whether the formula is satisfiable because the formula uses integers (and the model qfnra-nlsat finds a solution over the reals). It therefore acts as a no-op and produces the same subgoal it got. The first tactic in the or-else list that does not throw an exception becomes the tactic to decide the outcome. So qfnra-nlsat decides that the goal could not be reduced.

By using and-then instead you are basically reducing the goal using first qfnra-nlsat. If it succeeds, it produces either no sub-goals or a sub-goal with the formula "false". The smt tactic knows to handle these cases, where the sat and unsat cases are handled very efficiently.

There are other alternatives. In particular, if you want to use or-else as part of some larger set of alternatives, the approach is:

```
 (check-sat-using (or-else (and-then qfnra-nlsat fail) (and-then smt fail)))
```

It causes a failure to be signaled if qfnra-nlsat creates non-true and non-false subgoals. Then upon failure, the smt tactic is applied.

Comment: Thanks so much Nikolaj.  The second approach was superior for my use case because it returns a model in the integers when followed-up with `(get-model)`.  The first method returns a model where x=1, y=1, and z=to_int(sqrt(2)), presumably left over from nlsat.